# Push Notification From JAVA WebApp to Android

Tags: push-notification, android-notifications

I have an problem to send notification from java WebApplication to Android Application. I don't know how to send this push notification from JAVA webapplication.

Comment: Have you tried something so far?

Comment: i tried. i am able to send notification using FCM from firebase console, But not from appServer like Tomcat.